Starting with 2014 "+" signs and 2015 "−" signs, you delete signs until one remains. What’s left?
To allow new users to solve this puzzle and earn reputation points, I encourage all users whose reputation is 200 or more to not post an answer until 48 hours after this question is posted. Thank you!

A large whiteboard has 2014 "+" signs and 2015 "−" signs written on it. You are allowed to delete two of the symbols and replace them according to the following two rules.
If the two deleted symbols are the same, then replace them by "+".
If the two deleted symbols are different, then replace them by "−".
You repeat this until there is only one symbol left.
Which symbol is it?  Justify your answer.

Attribution:  UK Mathematical Olympiad for Girls 2014

Notice that, if you set + = 0 and - = 1, then the mod 2 of the sum does not change under either transformation. Hence, the final sum must be equivalent to the original sum, 2015, mod 2. Therefore the last symbol is a -.

+1 Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  Fast and correct; I’m impressed.

Nice solve! I noticed it is the number of strokes mod 2 :-)

Excellent PSE start! Equivalent to your reasoning, notice the invariant:  nzbhag bs - fvtaf vf bqq

Now that an officially new user has answered let me remark that + and - cry out to be read as

 +1 and -1

and the entire thing can naturally be interpreted as

 the product.

In fact, even more directly, we can read the given cluster of signs without modification as

 one compound operator.

This may not look right at first glance because with so many symbols it is rarely if ever encountered in an actual formula. But you may have seen something like x = 5 - - 2. Here the "- -" results in an effective "+" and there is no reason, in principle, not to stack this kind of transformation. For example, the Python interpreter will happily accept something like
>>> a,b,c = 5,1,-2
>>> 
>>> +++++a
5
>>> -+-+-+b
-1
>>> c++-++-++--+a
3


I think this answer is equivalent to BlazingSnow's answer, but instead of assigning numbers to the symbols and then reducing mod 2, I do a case analysis and observe parity of the count of each symbol:
The first operation, replacing two identical symbols with a +:

Removing the two symbols leaves the parity of both symbols the same
Adding a + changes the parity of the + symbols

The second operation, replacing two different symbols with -:

Removing the two symbols changes the parity of both symbols
Adding a - changes the parity of the - symbols back to what it was before

So, neither operation can change the parity of - symbols. They also both change the parity of + symbols, but this observation is not necessary to determine the answer. The parity of - symbols at the beginning is odd, and thus must remain odd. When there is only one symbol remaining, it can't be a + because the parity of - symbols would be even, which we know can never happen.

We can delete any two symbols so order doesn't matter, it suffices to track the counts: let p, m be the number of plus and minus symbols.
We have three kinds of operations:

delete two +, create a +: p-1, m if p >= 2
delete two -, create a +: p+1, m-2 if m >= 2
delete a + and -, create a -: p-1, m if p >= 1, m >= 1

Can we end with a -? We can use (2) 1007 times to get 3021, 1. Then we can use (3) 3021 times to get 0, 1.
Can we end with a +? No! If we look carefully at the rules we see that

(1) and (3) keep m the same
(2) decreases m by 2

Both moves keep m % 2 the same, so the final value of m must be odd. There is only one end state with one symbol and odd m: 0, 1. Therefore we will always end with - no matter what moves we make and what order we do them in. The move sequence to get there is repeat (2) until we reach some state p', 1 and then repeat (3) until we get 0, 1.
If the starting m was even, then we know that the final state must have

one symbol
and even m parity

The only such state is 1, 0. Similarly the move sequence is repeat (2) until we get p', 0 then repeat (1) until we get 1, 0.
If we start with an odd number of - we will end with a -, otherwise we will end with a +.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Straightforward thinking:
There are three ways to remove two signs:

Remove two +s, then add one back (effectively removing one +)
Remove one + and one -, then add a - (also effectively removing one +)
Remove two -s, then add a +

Noteworthy is that -s can only be removed in pairs, and it starts with 2015 of them. So if just one sign is left, it must be a -, as the number of - is always odd and never even.

Initially, there are an odd number of - signs.  Neither of the two permitted operations can change the fact that there are an odd number of - signs.  Therefore, there will ALWAYS be an odd number of - signs; which means that if we can ever get to the point where there's only one sign, it must be a -.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Answer: -
No matter how many + symbols there are, they can all be reduced to a single + by removing them 2 at a time. No matter how many - symbols there are, all except the last one, can be replaced by + by removing them 2 at a time. After removing all symbols except the last - symbol, all other symbols have been replaced by +. Replacing the + and the last - symbol leaves -.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Or without a brain:

remove 1007 pairs of "-" : you now have 2014+1007=3021 "+" and a single "-"
recursively remove "+" by coupling them with the only "-"
end up with the pair "+/-" which gives "-"


That is one way to remove all but one symbol. Now you have to prove that all the others result in the same symbol being left over.

I expected such a comment. That's where I find the question ambiguous : I like to understand the unicity of the answer is asserted. Of course the best answer is the product one. Or alternatively you can notice that transformations conserve the parity of the "bars", where "-" is one bar and "+" is 2 bars, if one symbol is left it must have an odd number of bars i.e one bar, so it's a "-".

@jackclash Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Essentially this answer uses meta information. You could argue: if this is a well-posed puzzle then the answer must be independent of how often you apply each rule and in which order. Therefore I can just pick any reduction and claim that this must be the answer in every case. Depending on context people consider this kind of argument either as cheating or as very clever.

Well explained. As a sudoku player, we have the same dilemma : some of the most powerfull solving technics assert the uniqueness of the solution. Some consider it cheaty, others don't.

It was my first thought as well. It's pretty easy to see what the answer is and the question could use a "show that it can't be the other symbol"

I think your comment about parity of the "bars" is the best answer so far.

@quarague I think the question would still be well-posed even if the answer is "it could be either" (and a justification would consist of two sequences of transformations giving different final signs). Indeed, you quite often see multiple-choice versions where that is explicitly one of the options.

From My knowledge and persective as

"+""+"="+"
"+""-"="-"
"-""-"="+"

as there are 2014 "+" and 2015 "-" , let aside 1 "-"
so there are 2014 "+" and 2014 "-".
So any way we pair them we will get "+" sign and getting it pair with the remaining "-" we will get "-"
so "-" i the final ans

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!
